# how do you background a ssh process?

Tags: ssh, job-control

I know you can suspend a ssh session with ~^z, but is there also a way to background it so that it continues working while you do something else in the local shell?

Answer (score 12):

If you're trying to run a process remotely, and you don't care about keeping the ssh session open, you may want to look at using `screen`.  It will allow you to run your process in the "background", and it will keep running after you logout.

First, `ssh` over to the remote box, then from there use `screen` and start your process, and you can give your `screen` a session name if you want.  You won't really notice anything different, but start your process in that session.  You can than exit out of the `screen` session by using the command `Ctrl-a d`.  It will look something like this:

```
user@remotebox:~$ screen -S foobarsession
user@remotebox:~$ startmyprocess
[detached from 4865.foobarsession]
user@remotebox:~$
```

You can then exit out of your ssh session, and the process will keep running.  To reconnect to the `screen` session later on, ssh back to the remote box and use `screen -r` to reconnect.  You can use `screen -ls` to list the sessions.

```
user@remotebox:~$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        4865.foobarsession     (10/05/2012 11:10:57 AM)     (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user
user@remotebox:~$ screen -r foobarsession
user@remotebox:~$ screen -ls
        4865.foobarsession     (10/05/2012 11:10:57 AM)     (Attached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user
user@remotebox:~$
```

Or, if `screen` isn't installed, you could use the `nohup` command on the remote box.  Wikipedia explains that well:

```
Nohupping backgrounded jobs is typically used to avoid terminating them when logging
off from a remote SSH session. A different issue that often arises in this situation
is that ssh is refusing to log off ("hangs"), since it refuses to lose any data
from/to the background job(s).  This problem can also be overcome by redirecting all
three I/O streams:

nohup ./myprogram > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &
```

So you could do something like:

```
ssh -n -f user@remotebox "sh -c 'cd /foo/bar; nohup ./myprogram > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &'"
```

Answer (score 9):

After ~^z execute `bg` and the stopped process will continue to execute in background. Works with all processes not just ssh.

P.S.: With `fg` you foreground the backgrounded process again. And just for the record: The ~ is only needed to distinguish whether the suspension should be on the local machine (with ~ --> the ssh client) or on the server (without ~ --> whatever process is currently running in foreground on the server)

Comment: In theory, this should work, but sometimes I just can't get it to background. It tries and then stops (pauses) the ssh process.

Comment: And when I revive the ssh process, it says "tcsetattr: Interrupted system call"